# UIScrollView scrolling speed

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, scroll, vertical-scrolling

Is there any way to reduce the speed of scrolling in the UIScrollView, I tried to use  `scrollRectToVisible: animated: NO` to accomplish this (by setting the animation to NO) but seems it's not the right way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017524/change-uiscrollview-scroll-speed  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719753/iphone-uiscrollview-speed-check

Comment: No, sorry this is my first post! My post is about the scrolling speed!

Answer (score 8):

You can use a simple uiview animation to do that..

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
[scrollview scrollRectToVisible:rect animated:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

that's the only way I am aware of.

ios 4 way (this will not work on iphones still running 3.x) :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^(void){
    [scrollview scrollRectToVisible:rect animated:NO];
}];
```

Comment: Thanks Bastian, but this doesn't work at all! and Apple discourage using the method : `setAnimationDuration` [http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html]

Comment: that depends... the new functions won't work on a device still running 3.x os, so if you want to support all ios devices you have to use them. However I added the "new" way to my answer.

Comment: No, Bastian is definitely right. You just have to adapt his sample to your code.

Comment: i Was using this : `[scrollViewPaging scrollRectToVisible: currentFrame animated: no]`, how can i adapt this?

Comment: I just tried it in my code. It won't automatic scroll to make a rect visible.. you have to put the point of the origin of the rect in.

Comment: you can simply use the same function with animated:NO ... it works in my sample

Comment: Thanks, this work only when scrolling outside my current frame(my scrollView), when i scroll the scrollView this code has no effect.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is not exactly what you asked for but it may help you to set deceleration rate with `UIScrollView` property

```
@property(nonatomic) float decelerationRate
```

Comment: Thanks Damien for the reply, i will investigate if i can use it.