# How to decrease scrolling speed of UIScrollview?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

How to decrease scrolling speed of UIScrollview in swift 1.2 ?

Reference

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561992/sensitivity-scroll-speed-of-uiscrollview-with-paging)

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017524/change-uiscrollview-scroll-speed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sensitivity/Scroll speed of UIScrollView with paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561992/sensitivity-scroll-speed-of-uiscrollview-with-paging)

Answer (score 3):

Implement this code on viewDidLoad

```
yourScrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast
```